# how to fill a viewmodel EF 4.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am working on asp.net MVC 3 project. I am using EF 4.1 code first approach. I have entity class called disputes. It maps to a table in database name tblDisptes. It has three properties names Lastviewedby, Lastupdatedby, LastRespondedBy ... all three integers. I have created a viewmodel 'disputeviewmodel' with three more properties  Lastviewedbyname, Lastupdatedbyname, LastRespondedByname and a property named dispute. Now my repository function returns list of disputes. how to convert this list to List of disputeviewmodel so that these three properties are filled with the names ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view model doesn't really need a property named `dispute`. A view model should not reference your domain models.

As far as the mapping is concerned one possibility is to manually do it but that could quickly become cumbersome with more complex models:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    IEnumerable<disputes> disputes = ... fetch from repo
    IEnumerable<disputeviewmodel> disputeViewModels = disputes.Select(x => new disputeviewmodel
    {
        Lastviewedbyname = x.Lastviewedby,
        Lastupdatedbyname = x.Lastupdatedby,
        LastRespondedByname = x.LastRespondedBy
    });
    return View(disputeViewModels);
}
```

So a better approach would be to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/):

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    IEnumerable<disputes> disputes = ... fetch from repo
    IEnumerable<disputeviewmodel> disputeViewModels = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<disputes>, IEnumerable<disputeviewmodel>>(disputes);
    return View(disputeViewModels);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. how Lastviewedbyname, Lastupdatedbyname, LastRespondedByname of disputeViewModels will be filled? because dispute does not have those. I need to manipulate Lastviewedby, Lastupdatedby, LastRespondedBy of dispute and fill Lastviewedbyname, Lastupdatedbyname, LastRespondedByname of viewmodel

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, that's something that your database access layer should worry about. The joins should be performed there. Your repository should already return a domain model that contains all the necessary information. That's why it is always a good idea to define a repository per aggregate root.

Comment: If I use AutoMapper, then Lastviewedbyname, Lastupdatedbyname, LastRespondedByname of viewmodel will be empty ? because dispute doesn't have these properties.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, that's true. So you will have to modify your repository and data access layer so that it returns a domain object that contains the corresponding names after querying your database and doing the necessary joins between the tables. It's not something that is really related to ASP.NET MVC. It's more of a data access question that you are having here.

Answer (score 0):

Why your Dispute doesn't look like that?

```
class Dispute
{
    public User LastViewedBy;
    public User Lastupdatedbyname
    public User LastRespondedByname
}
```

That's how it should look. Then problem solved. When you query for Disputes you already have Users (with there usernames) ready.

Comment: Dispute table doesnt have name. It holds Ids. and in view model I need names conditionally. Like If dispute.usertype =1 then lastViewedBy = PersonName else lastViewedBy = BusinessName

Comment: Well you are using code first. So database is generated based on you POCO entities. If You create Dispute like in my example table will also contain ID's but when you query for Dispute it will do joins for you. I don't understand where do you get PersonName, BusinessName from.